# How to convert utc to string in momentjs?

Tags: javascript, string, momentjs, utc

I want to use moment for this.

`moment("date","YYYYMMDD").fromNow();   // ~~ years ago example`

I get UTC from MongoDB createAt. but I don't know convert UTC to string (variable date).

ex) `mongodb_createAt = 2018-09-18T12:22:19.491Z`

this mongodb_createAt convert to string(date)

I want to utc convert to date string..

I want to display ~~ years ago (like youtube)

How to ??

thanks.

Comment: Feels like you are confused. `moment(mongodb_createAt).fromNow();` should help.

Answer (score 1):

You could use momentjs's `.humanize()` method to achieve this.

First, you'll need to calculate the duration between your timestamp `2018-09-18T12:22:19.491Z` and the current time. Once you have this duration, you can then make use of `.humanize()` like so:

```js
var mongodb_createAt = '2018-09-18T12:22:19.491Z';
var millisecondsElapsed = moment(mongodb_createAt).diff(moment());
var displayString = moment.duration(millisecondsElapsed).humanize(true);

console.log(displayString) // eg 17 hours ago
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Note that the `true` argument passed to `.humanize(true)` adds the tense to the `displayString` string - ie true causes a result like "17 hours ago" rather than just "17 hours"

For more information on the `humanize()` method, [see the official documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/humanize/)

Answer (score 0):

Look at moment documentation https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/

Try `moment().fromNow();` it should output `... years ago`